# Deadlock when calling two synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, dining-philosopher

```
class Downloader extends Thread {
    private InputStream in;
    private OutputStream out;
    private ArrayList<ProgressListener> listeners;
    public Downloader(URL url, String outputFilename) throws IOException {
        in = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputFilename);
        listeners = new ArrayList<ProgressListener>();
    }
    public synchronized void addListener(ProgressListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
    public synchronized void removeListener(ProgressListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private synchronized void updateProgress(int n) {
        for (ProgressListener listener: listeners)
            listener.onProgress(n);
    }
    public void run() {
        int n = 0, total = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, n);
                total += n;
                updateProgress(total);
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

The above code is from the book "seven concurrency models in seven weeks". The book says the above code is having potential for the deadlock as the the synchronized method updateProgress calls a alien method[onProgress] that might acquire another lock. 
Since we acquire two locks without right order, the deadlock might occur.

Can anyone explain how the deadlock happens in the above scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A deadlock would not occur with just the above code. It would require other code as well to cause a deadlock.

Comment: If this was called from multiple threads, the is there any potential for deadlock?

Comment: The book says to avoid the deadlock, use the defensive copying

Comment: The `updateProgress` method calls listeners. Since you don't control the code in these listeners' `onProgress` methode, you don't want to make the calls within the synchronized block.

Comment: I don't see the deadlock.  The code above calls `updateProgress` and the listeners on a single thread.  So that thread already holds a lock on the `Downloader` object, and Java monitors (what `synchronized` does) guarantee that a thread can always acquire a lock it already holds.  You may have to post more information for us to help you.

Comment: @markspace The problem occurs if the listener has its own locks. `run` holds the `Downloader` monitor then calls `onProgress` which locks some other monitor. If some other thread tries to call a method on the listener that is synchronized as well and that methods calls `addListener` there's a risk of a deadlock

Comment: A common pattern is for classes to implement the Listener interface and do something like `addListener(this)`. If this is done in a `synchronized` method, and the `onProgress` method is synchronized or calls other synchronized method, there's a real chance that you'll deadlock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to make the objects you use with `synchronized` private.

Since you synchronize on the `Downloader`, you don't know whether other threads synchronize on the `Downloader` too.

The following listener causes a deadlock:

```
MyProgressListener extends ProgressListener {

     public Downloader downloader;
     public void onProgress(int n) {
         Thread t = new Thread() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 synchronized(downloader) {
                     // do something ...
                 }
             }
         };
         t.start();
         t.join();
     }
}
```

#### Code that deadlocks:

```
Downloader d = new Downloader(...);
MyProgressListener l = new MyProgressListener();
l.downloader = d;
d.addListener(l);
d.run();
```

The following will happen if you run that code:

1. the main thread reaches the `updateProgress` and aquires a lock on the `Downloader`
2. the `MyProgressListener`'s `onProgress` method is called and the new thread `t` is started
3. the main thread reaches `t.join();`

In this situation the main thread cannot procede until `t` is finished, but for `t` to finish, the main thread would have to release it's lock on the `Downloader`, but that won't happen since the main thread can't procede -> **Deadlock**

Answer (score 2):

First off, recall that the keyword `synchronized`, when applied to a a class, implies locking the whole object this method belongs to. Now, let's sketch out another couple of objects triggering the deadlock:

```
class DLlistener implements ProgressListener {

  private Downloader d;

  public DLlistener(Downloader d){
      this.d = d;
      // here we innocently register ourself to the downloader: this method is synchronized
      d.addListener(this);
  }

  public void onProgress(int n){
    // this method is invoked from a synchronized call in Downloader
    // all we have to do to create a dead lock is to call another synchronized method of that same object from a different thread *while holding the lock*
    DLthread thread = new DLThread(d);
    thread.start();
    thread.join();
  }
}

// this is the other thread which will produce the deadlock
class DLThread extends Thread {
   Downloader locked;
  DLThread(Downloader d){
    locked = d;
  }
  public void run(){
    // here we create a new listener, which will register itself and generate the dead lock
    DLlistener listener(locked);
    // ...
  }
}
```

One way to avoid the dead lock is to postpone the work done in `addListener` by having internal queues of listeners waiting to be added/removed, and have `Downloader` taking care of those by itself periodically. This ultimately depends on `Downloader.run` inner working of course.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem in this code:

```
for (ProgressListener listener: listeners)
            listener.onProgress(n);
```

When one thread, which holds a lock, calls an external method 
like this one (onProgress) then you cannot guarantee that
implementation of this method won't try to obtain other lock, 
which could be held by different thread. This may cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a classic example that shows the kind of hard-to-debug problems the author is trying to avoid.

The class `UseDownloader` is created and `downloadSomething` is called.

As the download progresses, the `onProgress` method is called. Since this is called from within the synchronized block, the `Downloader` motinor is locked. Inside our `onProgress` method, we need to lock our own resource, in this case `lock`. So when we are trying to synchronize on `lock` we are holding the `Downloader` monitor.

If another thread has decided that the download should be canceled, it will call `setCanceled`. This first tests `done` so it synchronized on the `lock` monitor and then calls `removeListener`. But `removeListener` requires the `Downloader` lock.

This kind of deadlock can be hard to find because it doesn't happen very often.

```
  public static final int END_DOWNLOAD = 100;

  class UseDownloader implements ProgressListener {
    Downloader d;
    Object lock = new Object();
    boolean done = false;

    public UseDownloader(Downloader d) {
      this.d = d;
    }
    public void onProgress(int n) {
      synchronized(lock) {
        if (!done) {
          // show some progress
        }
      }
    }

    public void downloadSomething() {
      d.addListener(this);
      d.start();
    }

    public boolean setCanceled() {
      synchronized(lock) {
        if (!done) {
          done = true;
          d.removeListener(this);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The following example leads to a deadlock because the MyProgressListener tries to acquire the Downloader lock while it's already acquired.

```
class MyProgressListener extends ProgressListener {
    private Downloader myDownloader;

    public MyProgressListener(Downloader downloader) {
        myDownloader = downloader;
    }

    public void onProgress(int n) {
        // starts and waits for a thread that accesses myDownloader
    }
}

Downloader downloader = new Downloader(...);
downloader.addListener(new MyListener(downloader));
downloader.run();
```

Comment: Java monitors are reentrant. Acquiring the lock twice on the same thread works.